# Check if folder exists does not work as expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, directory

When I attempt to check if a folder exists, my code suggests it exists, even if it doesn't.

```
string folder = @"C:\LWA";
if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Folder Exists");
}
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Your conditional statement reads: "if NOT folder exists, display Folder exists".

Comment: Remove the `!`, otherwise you check if it _not_ exists. Read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2kd6eb2.aspx

Comment: Something so stupid.. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` condition and message don't match.

```
! Directory.Exists(blah)
```

will be true if the directory `blah` does *not* exist.

The `!` operator *inverts* the boolean value you give it.